# Add multiple cross sell products to cart from product page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm surprised im asking this as i would assume it is fairly easy to do but i've been trying and playing with plugins for days and not able to get the result i need.

I am trying to add multiple cross sell options to a woocommerce product so that a user can select multiple add-on products and add them to the cart with the main product from the product page.

Fore example: If the main product is a toy car, the add-on options might be batteries, extra remote control, etc. The customer could check the items they want and all would be separately added to the cart (by separately i mean so the customer could later decide to remove the toy car from the cart, but the batteries and extra remote would still remain in the cart until they were also removed).

I have tried various things including: product variations (core), product bundles (woo and yith), product addons (woo and yith), composite products (woo and yith). None can do all of the above.

If anyone can suggest a way to do it with either core or a plugin i would be VERY grateful!

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while and I assume you already found the answer, but in case you haven't, you may add (manually) all the products that matches the product in the cart. You can do so in the product's page (admin panel) in "linked products", where "Cross-Sells" are the ones that will show in the cart.

The only thing is that by default, WooCommerce allows only 2 products to be linked. You may override that limit by inserting in your theme's "functions.php" file, the following line.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_columns', 'change_cross_sells_columns' );

    function change_cross_sells_columns( $columns ) {
    return 6;
    }
```

In the example above, "6" is the limit. You may use any number, but you should use it wisely, as too many products shown in the cart will only confuse customers.

I hope this helps.